# I get error using "type":"module" in node js

Tags: node.js, express, import, module, cpanel

I'm new in nodejs.
I made simple node app in Cpanel with expressjs:

```js
import express from 'express';
const app = express();
const port = '';

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!');
})

app.get('/about', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello about!');
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`);
})
```

my package.js is this.

```
{
"name": "myapp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "App",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
    "test": "test"
},
"author": "Name Surname",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1"
},
"type":"module"
```

}

but I have this error.

```
App 3183657 output: /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80
App 3183657 output:     return originalRequire.apply(this, arguments);
App 3183657 output:                         ^
App 3183657 output: Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/makyansystems/public_html/simple.makyan.online/index.js from /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js not supported.
App 3183657 output: Instead change the require of index.js in /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
App 3183657 output:     at Module.require (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:80:25)
App 3183657 output:     at loadApplication (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:243:2)
App 3183657 output:     at setupEnvironment (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:214:2)
App 3183657 output:     at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js:133:1) {
App 3183657 output:   code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
App 3183657 output: }
App 3183657 output: Node.js v20.3.1
```

But works without "type":"module" or with "type":"commonJS"

In local works fine both versions. I read that in future good to use "import" instead of "require".
What is the problem.

Comment: Limitation of cpanel hosting. Change your hosting provider as thing kind of thing should not be happening in 2023 or implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74828605/21972629) solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the JS script (you can see it in the error message as: `/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby27/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/node-loader.js`) used by CPanel is importing your code using `require(...)` and is therefore expecting your script to be a CommonJS module, not ES module.

Because of that you must use `require` instead of `import` in your code. Alternatively you can use dynamic `import()` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!In local server have no problems and have no problems using commonjs. As I must deploy and use my app online, I want to solve this kind of problems at start. Before I used require, but not modern is using import...

Comment: @IgorDavidMakyan change the hosting